# Variable as part of the generated filename

Tags: python, xml, variables, filenames

Example:
var = "string"

and I want an xml output file: string.xml

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams to be too easy... maybe i did not get the question right:

```
var = "String"
fileName = var + ".xml"
print fileName
```

this will print

```
String.xml
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried this, but I had an error and I just thought that the solution is not good.